# Download all entries in RSS feed using ROME

Tags: rss, rss-reader, rome

I'm using ROME from Scala to download RSS feeds, but it's only grabbing a subset of the entries. For example, Google Reader finds at least 61 entries for [Bing Images](http://feeds.feedburner.com/bingimages), but ROME only finds 10 entries. Here's some code:

```
val sfi = new SyndFeedInput
val url = new URL("http://feeds.feedburner.com/bingimages")
val feed = sfi.build(new XmlReader(url))
println(feed.getEntries.size) // prints "10", but should find more
```

This isn't specific to the feed; [this Flickr feed](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=49598046@N00&lang=en-us&format=rss_200) has many entries, but in this case ROME finds 20 entries.

How do I get the complete list of entries in the feed?